# Getting the State of a Toggle Button

Tags: java, android

I may be going about this all wrong, but I have a view that contains a few ToggleButtons and a Save button. When the Save button is pressed, I want to collect the states of the various toggles as boolean values. I have tried the following in the onClickHandler for the Save button:

```
ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
boolean pol = tb.isChecked();
```

and I would expect *pol* to be set to the state of *button1*, but it keeps being set to *true*. Of course I have tried this with the button in both states.

Thanks

Comment: If your button1 always being ON, why isChecked() would return false?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
boolean pol = false;
tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(tb.isChecked()) {
                pol = true; 
                } else {
                    pol = false;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Additional example available at http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f775eda0a3aaa47646b1a/android.widget.ToggleButton?tag=antelope&fullSource=1